# Shortest proof for 'hairy ball' theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I want to make a project at differential geometry about the [Hairy Ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) and its applications. I was thinking of including a proof of the theorem in the project. Using the [Poincare-Hopf Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) seems easy enough, but I was thinking that this proves the desired result using a stronger theorem (just like proving Liouville's Theorem in complex analysis using Picard's theorem).

> Is there a simple proof of the fact that there is no continuous non-zero vector field on the even dimensional sphere? It is good enough if the proof works only for $S^2$, because that is the case I will be focusing on in the applications.

Comment: `[insert joke about hairy balls here]`.

Comment: How can one prove it via Hopf Index Theorem? Since you said it was easy :)

Comment: I asked this question more than 10 years ago. I honestly don't remember :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an elegant and self-contained proof by Milnor: Analytic proofs of the "hairy ball theorem", American Math. Monthly, 85 (1978), 521-524. The paper is reprinted in his collected works and can be downloaded for pay here:

http://www.jstor.org/pss/2320860

Comment: Thank you. I'll probably use this :)

Comment: Please consider adding the proof to your answer. Linking to an answer behind a paywall is not nearly as useful to the community.

Comment: @Eric Wilson: I don't have the paper at my fingertips, but I remembered it as a real gem, so I retrieved its coordinates. I regret the paywall as much as anybody else. Fortunately the Monthly is widely available in math libraries.

Comment: @BeniBogosel If you (or anyone else) found this useful, perhaps you can edit the answer to include a summary of the contents.

Comment: @EricWilson: The sketch of the proof can be found in the following blog post: http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/analyzing-the-hairy-ball-theorem/  I thank Christian Blatter for posting the link. In the library of my university I could read it. The blog post summarizes the proof.

Comment: @EricWilson Everyone is goint to download at scihub anyway.

Answer (score 43):

The simplest I can remember off the top of my head is this:

---

Assume there is such a vector field. Let $v_x$ denote the vector at the point $x$. Now, define the homotopy $H: S^2\times [0, 1] \rightarrow S^2$ by the following: $H(x, t)$ is the point $t\pi$ radians away from $x$ along the great circle defined by $v_x$. This gives a homotopy between the identity and the antipodal map on $S^2$, which is impossible, since the antipodal map has [degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) $-1$. Hence there can be no such vector field.

Comment: this also works for general dimensions, with the same argument.
define $H(x,t) := \cos(t) \, x  + \sin(t) \, \nu_x$, as in hirsch's differential topology, which gives you a homotopy between $id_{\mathbb S^m}$ and $-id_{\mathbb S^m}$.
we have $\deg (-id_{\mathbb S^m}) = (-1)^{m+1}$.

Comment: Note that reflection in one coordinate has degree -1, so that the map from x to -x has degree (-1)^(n+1) where n is the dimension of the sphere. Bonus fact that any fixed point free map from the sphere to itself is homotopic to the antipodal map via parameterized normalized line segments between -x and f(x), necessarily not crossing the origin.

Answer (score 3):

The proof can be found on this site:

http://people.ucsc.edu/~lewis/Math208/hairyball.pdf

Comment: Right, except this is not "the proof" but is "Milnor's proof".