# Any tangent vector field on S^2 has a singular point

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, vector-fields, spheres, singularity

Is there an intuitive geometric proof to this?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90737/shortest-proof-for-hairy-ball-theorem/90741) might help.

Answer (score 2):

If a singular point of a tangent vector field $X$ means that $X(x)=0$, your assertion is not true. There exists parallelizable spheres, $S^1,S^3,S^7$ which are the only parallelizable spheres after results of Bott, Kervaire, Milnor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the S^2 sphere! Thank you

Comment: @user142702, if you meant that, then **edit** the question to that it means exactly what you mean.